# krypton ssh stops to work after upgrading to macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: ssh-keys

I have just upgraded macOS to Catalina 10.15.5 and ssh using krypton has stopped to work. First I got an error `Enter PIN for 'Kryptonite iOS':` which I solved removing line `PKCS11Provider /usr/local/lib/kr-pkcs11.so` from .ssh/config like explained in https://github.com/kryptco/kr/issues/301

However, after doing that, it seems like trying to get confirmation from iPhone is never tried.

I get this:

```
ssh username@192.168.0.4                
no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_krypton: No such file or directory
no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
jlr@192.168.0.4: Permission denied (publickey).
```

My config file is:

```
# Added by Krypton
Host *
        ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/krssh %h %p
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_krypton
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

I was able to connect just before the update to Catalina 10.15.5, no changes on the server side.

I have tried to reinstall kr and also unpair and pair again the device, but none of these solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the line

```
IdentityAgent ~/.kr/krd-agent.sock
```

to .ssh/config file as explained by lumaxis in https://github.com/kryptco/kr/issues/307